# pandas groupby return a boolean vector

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series database where I would like to group the data to compare them both to another cell in the same row, and the previous value.

The code below will return a vector against the whole dataframe, but if I try to group it I get a dataframe with apply() and an error with agg or transform.

Sample data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'group': [1, 1, 1, 2,2,2,1,2, 1], 'target': [100,100,100,100,10,10,10,10,50],'val' :[90,80,70,4,120,6,60,8, 50] })
df


 group  target  val
0   1    100    90
1   1    100    80
2   1    100    70
3   2    100    4
4   2     10    120
5   2     10    6
6   1     10    60
7   2     10    8
8   1     50    50
```

Here is my attempt at a function

```
def spike(df):
    high = df['val'] > df['target']+25
    rising = df['val'] > df['val'].shift()
    return high & rising

print(spike(df))
print( df.groupby('group').apply(spike))
```

Output

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
dtype: bool


       0      1      2      6      8
group                                   
1      False  False  False  False  False
2      False   True  False  False   True
```

Here is my output, I was trying to get the second output to look like the first except row 6 should be false.

Answer (score 1):

You are over thinking it:

```
shift = df.groupby('group')['val'].shift()
df['val'].gt(df['target']+25) & df['val'].gt(shift)
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
dtype: bool
```